# ASP.net attachment then refresh page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a c# project using ASP .net.

I have a list of reports with a hyperlink for each, which calls the web server, retrieves 
a PDF and then returns the PDF for the user to save or open:

ASPX page:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <a href="#" onclick="SubmitFormToOpenReport();">Open Report 1</a>
<td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

ASP.Net:

```
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=report.pdf");
context.Response.Charset = "";
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
context.Response.BinaryWrite(myReport);
context.Response.Flush();
```

This works as expected, however I would like it to also refresh the page with an updated list.

I am having trouble as the single request/response is returning the report.

Is there a way to refresh the page as well?

While there is a correct response, feel free to include answers which details alternative solutions/ideas for doing this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately your current approach is a dead end. The nature of HTTP is single request, single response. A response can only have one code - "OK, here is some data, please download it". "Go here instead" is a different code. You're describing something much more complex - a sequence of instructions. First "here is a file", then "redirect yourself to another resource". The implications of making this work should be a clue - when should the browser redirect? When the user selects a location to save the file? After the file is finished downloading?

To do what you're describing, you could have the JavaScript open the PDF in a new window and also re-load the current window.

Comment: +1.  Exactly what I was thinking.  We did this by having a ashx file to generate the PDF.  We have a link that on the client side, opens a new window to the ashx, but then posts back to the original page to refresh.

Comment: Thanks Rex, that pointed me in the right direction.
I submitted the form in javascript and made the target="_blank". This opened the PDF in a new window (which closed once the user clicks save or cancel). Then the next line I submitted a refresh form.

Comment: @David - out of curiosity, what is an ashx file?

Comment: @Russel an ashx is an HttpHandler - sort of like a page, except way more basic and at a much lower level - by default it does nothing, and it only has one method, `ProcessRequest`, where you write directly to the response. It's much more appropriate for situations where you are serving something other than a true webform/HTML page.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `response.redirect(request.url.tostring)` after your `context.Response.Flush();`